# Facebook Graph API Music decide between Artist and Album

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How do I differentiate between Artists and Albums in Facebooks Graph API?
When searching for

```
new GraphRequest(
        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
        "/me/music",
        null,
        HttpMethod.GET,
        new GraphRequest.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                response = graphResponse;
            }
        }
)
```

both Albums and Artists are returned. (Songs curiously aren't)
How do i decide if it's an album or an artist?

The `GraphResponse` looks like this

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "name": "The Marshall Mathers LP",
        "id": "112321302117017",
        "created_time": "2015-09-14T08:15:22+0000"
    },
    {
        "name": "Sabaton",
        "id": "7545529867",
        "created_time": "2015-08-14T11:43:03+0000"
    }
],
"paging": {
    "cursors": {
        "before": "MTEyMzIxMzAyMTE3MDE3",
        "after": "NzIzNDU0NjcwNgZDZD"
    }
}
```

How do I decide if it's an album or an artist?

Answer (score 0):

The docs at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/music/

state that the resulting array is

> ...a list of Page nodes.

so you could theoretically request every field available for a page:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/#Reading

Still, as far as I know, there is no distinction on page level between an artist page and an album page.

Comment: If I request every field for all pages, how can I then decide if the page is an album page or an artist page?

Comment: You can't... As I wrote